# Match PHP socket SSL options in Perl

Tags: php, perl, ssl, ssl-certificate

**Background:**

In some PHP code dealing with a 3rd party web-service, the following code works:

```
// connect to web-service
$remote_addr = "tcp://{$data['ip']}:{$data['port']}";
$socket = stream_socket_client($remote_addr, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$socket) throw "Couldn't create socket: $errstr\n";

// configure SSL options on socket
stream_context_set_option($socket, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $data['cert']);
stream_context_set_option($socket, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
stream_context_set_option($socket, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($socket, 'ssl', 'cafile', $data['cafile']);

// do SSL handshake
stream_set_blocking ($socket, true);
stream_socket_enable_crypto ($socket, true, STREAM_CRYPTO_METHOD_SSLv3_CLIENT);
stream_set_blocking ($socket, false);

//... start talking HTTP
```

We go on to wrap this PHP code in our own JSON-RPC web-service in order to call it from an in-house management system, written in Perl.

In profiling this "solution", I've discovered that I could greatly improve performance by removing the Perl-PHP (via HTTP) indirection. I've tried porting the code to Perl but have had issues matching the SSL options.

I'm using the `$ua->ssl_opts()` method of `LWP::UserAgent` to pass the correct options down to `Net::SSL` (`Crypt::SSLeay`). I've been using `strace` to determine whether the certificates are being read, and it looks like they are. However, I'm not sure whether `Net::SSL` succeeds in reading the key from the PEM.

**Question:**

What specific `$ua->ssl_opts()` arguments do I need to match the behaviour of the PHP code?

**Notes:**

- `$data['cert']` is the full path to a PEM file containing

  - Our "client" certificate - issued by the 3rd party
  - Our *non*-encrypted (RSA) private key - issued by the 3rd party
- `$data['cafile']` is the full path to the self-signed signing certificate - issued by the 3rd party
- I'm *not* looking for security advice about the plaintext nature of the private key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL pseudo-expert here. Going through your question and [both](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php) [docs](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), here's what seems to have parity:

1. `'local_cert'`

   **SSL_cert_file**. From [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.62/SSL.pm#SSL_cert_file).
2. `'verify_peer'`

   **verify_hostname**. From [here](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php) and [here](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.04/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm), again.
3. `'allow_self_signed'`

   *No parity.* However, this option is moot, since [you required `verify_peer` for that in the first place.](http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php)
4. `'cafile'`

   **SSL_ca_file**. Also from [here](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.62/SSL.pm#SSL_ca_file).

You'll also want to set [**SSL_version**](http://search.cpan.org/~sullr/IO-Socket-SSL-1.62/SSL.pm#SSL_version) to support your need for SSLv3. And, that appears to be it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it - I'm going crazy here :-) I'll try setting those options, but they look awfully close to the examples that haven't worked.  I could probably figure this out myself if I could reasonably debug the SSL library itself.

Comment: Ok, I'll accept your answer then ask another related to debugging SSL in Perl.

Comment: Can't give the bounty yet - won't let me - "not received enough attention".

Comment: @David-SkyMesh No hurry. Though, I admit I can't find _why_ it's locked out like that at your end, neither in meta, nor in [the errata of this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) on the current bounty system. I've flagged it for mod review, because I'm stumped, and it's clear what your intent happens to be!

Comment: @David-SkyMesh Although, I'm curious about getting a bound on when the bounty can first be granted, since my request for moderation hasn't been looked into so far and I still can't find the documentation. So, excuse the nag: are you able to grant it yet?

Comment: No, sorry. In the bounty box directly underneath the question I see "This question has not received enough attention.".

Comment: @David-SkyMesh Hm. Can we take it to chat? I'm curious if I can help you debug this issue!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9448/discussion-between-mrgomez-and-david-skymesh)

Answer (score 0):

There is a test file in the Crypt::SSLeay module, withthat your are able to test your certificate/SSL connection.

perl eg/net-ssl-test -cert=certs/notacacert.pem -key=certs/notacakeynopass.pem -CAfile your_ca_file.ca -d GET test_url

You could use env vars to setup files/path:

from: [http://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::SSLeay](http://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aSSLeay)

```
# debugging (SSL diagnostics)
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;

# default ssl version
$ENV{HTTPS_VERSION} = '3';

# client certificate support
$ENV{HTTPS_CERT_FILE} = 'certs/notacacert.pem';
$ENV{HTTPS_KEY_FILE}  = 'certs/notacakeynopass.pem';
```

Comment: That's just the example from the man page for Crypt::SSLeay. It's literally the first thing I tried. Some things to note from my explanation above - (1) there's a 3rd party signing CA, and the key is in the same PEM, and (2) remote hostname verification shouldn't occur.

Comment: I'm using $ua->ssl_opts() precisely because the environment variables are undesirable (read global) -- they leak even when you _local_ize the environment changes.

Comment: Additionally, I did an strace -- I don't see the KEY file being read.

Comment: Any recommendations on debugging Net::SSL?

Comment: Ok, I see you mentioned the CAFile with the test script --- also doesn't work. I wonder if I have to do something to stop the "peer verification".